# How do i bring back input response working on virtualbox inside Wayland session

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, input-devices

**THE issue:**
(Under 20.04 LTS) The interface scale in x11 session environment still giving a headache to some people (like me).  So i decided to use Wayland (that have the option to set a minor interface scale). 
As a developer, i have a lot of virtual machines running in virtualbox, BUT figured out that virtualbox have some conficts/issues under Wayland (the cursor and keyboard just vanished and stop working [More specific: no key press detection, no click in any place you want...]).

Finally, turned looking for some info on internet and i didn't read anything useful about how can i implement a valid solution ([this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19043) included).

¿How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

At 6.1.28 version of virtualbox, the keyboard/mouse issue still happens, so
I expect that YOU can resolve with this steps, bro:

1. Poweroff all your running virtual machines.
2. If you have automatic updates turned off, update your current version of virtualbox (6.1.32 Actually) using APT repository (**please don't unistall it or it will brick the actually created signed boot**)
3. When it was already been updated, do this:

   - Download the brand new [Extension pack](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.32/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.32.vbox-extpack).
   - Download the brand new [Guest Additions](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.32/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.32.iso)
   - Go to File > Preferences > Extensions and delete old existing Extension Pack.
   - Install the new Extension Pack.
   - Inside virtual machine config you must create a new optical drive with the guest additions iso mounted.
4. Start (turn on) your graphical interface virtual machine and continue with guest additions installation (I recommend uninstall the old first. If you can have some issues, use the keyboard software that virtualbox provides under machine menu). When the install process has finished, reboot the virtual machine to see changes taking effect.
5. **The new GuestAdditions make some changes in Guest keyboard distribution during installation**, so before using you could adjust this topic in your guest OS.
6. At this point, you have been issue-purgued-out and smile like a child eating candy.

**Pending workaround:**
- For hot-keys binding issue you could disable **keyboard auto capture** (Virtualbox window > File > Preferences > Input > Unmark keyboard auto capture).
- [Solved] The GuestAdditions is now ignoring keyboard distribution (only for guest), working on a solution.