# Virtualbox not booting on Ubuntu 20.04 error code: 0x80004005

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, virtualbox, kali

I have a problem with installing Kali with Virtualbox on Ubuntu 20.04 (in dual boot with Windows 11).
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILwRmXx8kwg&t=5s .

I did everything from the turorial but when I press "Start" I get a peculiar error message:

[image: screenshot1]

When I run the command it tells me to run in the error message it says:

[image: screenshot2]

Alongside with the first error message I am also presented with the second, stating:

[image: screenshot3]

What shall I do? Please help me.
Best regards

Comment: Kali is not supported on this site.

Comment: Kali linux is not suported here. But take this: every time you update the kernel, u must re-sign the boot config prior to start a new/existing VM. Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392375/how-do-i-bring-back-input-response-working-on-virtualbox-inside-wayland-session)